# How to input cvs and get min and max values python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Read in the same hsv_2020_climo_data.csv file into Pandas DataFrame with the Date column as the index (similar to examples before).
Answer the following questions with formatted print statements.
What are the data types of each column? (i.e. 'MaxTemperature' dtype is int64)
What is the highest maximum temperature for the entire year?
What is the lowest minimum temperature for the entire year?
How much total rain did we get for 2020? (Hint you will need to handle the "Trace" values first)
Make a plot with Maximum Temperature, Minimum Temperature, and Average Temperature with labels and title.

Data below

```
Date     MaxTemperature  MinTemperature  AvgTemperature  Precipitation   Snowfall    SnowDepth
2020-01-01  53  31  42.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-01-02  54  45  49.5    3.42    0.0 0
2020-01-03  59  53  56.0    0.32    0.0 0
2020-01-04  56  31  43.5    0.08    0.0 0
2020-01-05  55  29  42.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-01-06  60  35  47.5    0.03    0.0 0
2020-01-07  55  35  45.0     T  0.0 0
2020-01-08  61  30  45.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-01-09  60  36  48.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-01-10  65  58  61.5     T  0.0 0
2020-01-11  72  50  61.0    1.08    0.0 0
2020-01-12  59  46  52.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-01-13  62  43  52.5    0.08    0.0 0
2020-01-14  64  60  62.0    0.96    0.0 0
2020-01-15  67  60  63.5    0.61    0.0 0
2020-01-16  60  42  51.0    0.03    0.0 0
2020-01-17  59  40  49.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-01-18  57  45  51.0    0.17    0.0 0
2020-01-19  45  27  36.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-01-20  28  22  25.0     T   T  0
2020-01-21  37  23  30.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-01-22  46  20  33.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-01-23  47  39  43.0    0.72    0.0 0
2020-01-24  54  40  47.0    0.19    0.0 0
2020-01-25  41  33  37.0     T  0.0 0
2020-01-26  49  29  39.0    0.03    0.0 0
2020-01-27  58  37  47.5    0.01    0.0 0
2020-01-28  60  31  45.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-01-29  50  44  47.0    0.03    0.0 0
2020-01-30  60  37  48.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-01-31  52  45  48.5     T  0.0 0
2020-02-01  50  37  43.5    0.06    0.0 0
2020-02-02  68  31  49.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-02-03  71  40  55.5     T  0.0 0
2020-02-04  67  55  61.0    0.18    0.0 0
2020-02-05  68  62  65.0    1.16    0.0 0
2020-02-06  64  36  50.0    1.49    0.0 0
2020-02-07  41  33  37.0     T   T  0
2020-02-08  53  32  42.5    0.10     T  0
2020-02-09  61  33  47.0     T  0.0 0
2020-02-10  57  49  53.0    1.78    0.0 0
2020-02-11  66  45  55.5    1.12    0.0 0
2020-02-12  70  44  57.0    1.31    0.0 0
2020-02-13  60  36  48.0    0.38    0.0 0
2020-02-14  41  26  33.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-02-15  54  22  38.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-02-16  58  42  50.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-02-17  56  38  47.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-02-18  62  46  54.0    1.32    0.0 0
2020-02-19  52  43  47.5     T  0.0 0
2020-02-20  47  33  40.0    0.85     T  0
2020-02-21  44  26  35.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-02-22  56  24  40.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-02-23  53  34  43.5    0.01    0.0 0
2020-02-24  55  44  49.5    0.62    0.0 0
2020-02-25  62  45  53.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-02-26  48  36  42.0    0.04     T  0
2020-02-27  46  31  38.5     T   T  0
2020-02-28  51  34  42.5     T  0.0 0
2020-02-29  55  36  45.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-03-01  66  34  50.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-03-02  60  52  56.0    0.44    0.0 0
2020-03-03  69  55  62.0    0.33    0.0 0
2020-03-04  60  51  55.5    0.04    0.0 0
2020-03-05  59  42  50.5    0.15    0.0 0
2020-03-06  56  37  46.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-03-07  58  30  44.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-03-08  65  35  50.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-03-09  68  45  56.5     T  0.0 0
2020-03-10  70  56  63.0    0.27    0.0 0
2020-03-11  66  51  58.5    0.12    0.0 0
2020-03-12  76  57  66.5    0.26    0.0 0
2020-03-13  67  54  60.5    0.14    0.0 0
2020-03-14  74  50  62.0    0.56    0.0 0
2020-03-15  61  44  52.5    1.07    0.0 0
2020-03-16  59  44  51.5    0.02    0.0 0
2020-03-17  74  53  63.5    0.24    0.0 0
2020-03-18  77  52  64.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-03-19  78  64  71.0     T  0.0 0
2020-03-20  72  60  66.0    1.11    0.0 0
2020-03-21  59  43  51.0    0.01    0.0 0
2020-03-22  66  43  54.5    0.07    0.0 0
2020-03-23  64  57  60.5    1.80    0.0 0
2020-03-24  76  57  66.5    2.96    0.0 0
2020-03-25  66  51  58.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-03-26  81  47  64.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-03-27  85  63  74.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-03-28  82  66  74.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-03-29  75  53  64.0    0.41    0.0 0
2020-03-30  70  52  61.0    0.02    0.0 0
2020-03-31  56  43  49.5    0.65    0.0 0
2020-04-01  62  39  50.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-02  70  38  54.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-03  75  42  58.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-04  78  54  66.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-05  81  54  67.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-06  83  52  67.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-07  74  62  68.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-08  80  63  71.5    0.24    0.0 0
2020-04-09  71  57  64.0    0.32    0.0 0
2020-04-10  60  40  50.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-11  71  37  54.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-12  66  54  60.0    3.02    0.0 0
2020-04-13  66  42  54.0     T  0.0 0
2020-04-14  59  39  49.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-15  61  34  47.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-16  69  36  52.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-17  76  45  60.5    0.07    0.0 0
2020-04-18  62  45  53.5    0.21    0.0 0
2020-04-19  63  46  54.5    1.41    0.0 0
2020-04-20  72  51  61.5    0.11    0.0 0
2020-04-21  76  50  63.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-22  68  42  55.0    0.29    0.0 0
2020-04-23  70  54  62.0    0.92    0.0 0
2020-04-24  73  56  64.5    0.01    0.0 0
2020-04-25  74  53  63.5    0.21    0.0 0
2020-04-26  61  41  51.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-27  72  38  55.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-04-28  77  53  65.0     T  0.0 0
2020-04-29  72  53  62.5    0.13    0.0 0
2020-04-30  71  48  59.5     T  0.0 0
2020-05-01  76  43  59.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-02  83  51  67.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-03  85  58  71.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-04  84  60  72.0     T  0.0 0
2020-05-05  76  56  66.0     T  0.0 0
2020-05-06  65  44  54.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-07  71  39  55.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-08  61  48  54.5    0.86    0.0 0
2020-05-09  64  40  52.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-10  73  39  56.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-11  68  43  55.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-12  66  48  57.0     T  0.0 0
2020-05-13  79  55  67.0    0.05    0.0 0
2020-05-14  85  61  73.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-15  84  67  75.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-16  86  62  74.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-17  79  65  72.0    0.23    0.0 0
2020-05-18  82  60  71.0     T  0.0 0
2020-05-19  71  54  62.5     T  0.0 0
2020-05-20  77  54  65.5    0.25    0.0 0
2020-05-21  79  57  68.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-22  82  63  72.5    1.52    0.0 0
2020-05-23  86  64  75.0    0.28    0.0 0
2020-05-24  88  65  76.5     T  0.0 0
2020-05-25  88  67  77.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-26  76  67  71.5    0.31    0.0 0
2020-05-27  79  61  70.0    0.74    0.0 0
2020-05-28  83  62  72.5    0.21    0.0 0
2020-05-29  83  64  73.5    0.18    0.0 0
2020-05-30  84  63  73.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-05-31  83  59  71.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-01  85  53  69.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-02  89  67  78.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-03  88  71  79.5    0.06    0.0 0
2020-06-04  87  68  77.5     T  0.0 0
2020-06-05  90  69  79.5    0.41    0.0 0
2020-06-06  91  68  79.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-07  91  71  81.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-08  84  75  79.5    0.43    0.0 0
2020-06-09  87  75  81.0    0.11    0.0 0
2020-06-10  92  65  78.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-11  85  61  73.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-12  88  61  74.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-13  90  58  74.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-14  92  62  77.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-15  83  61  72.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-16  81  60  70.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-17  80  63  71.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-18  85  61  73.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-19  91  64  77.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-20  94  66  80.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-21  88  69  78.5    0.14    0.0 0
2020-06-22  88  68  78.0    0.14    0.0 0
2020-06-23  87  70  78.5    0.25    0.0 0
2020-06-24  75  68  71.5    0.70    0.0 0
2020-06-25  85  70  77.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-06-26  75  68  71.5    0.15    0.0 0
2020-06-27  82  68  75.0    0.30    0.0 0
2020-06-28  90  73  81.5    0.25    0.0 0
2020-06-29  90  71  80.5    0.01    0.0 0
2020-06-30  88  70  79.0    0.84    0.0 0
2020-07-01  82  68  75.0    0.73    0.0 0
2020-07-02  89  68  78.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-03  94  71  82.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-04  92  71  81.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-05  93  71  82.0    0.47    0.0 0
2020-07-06  88  71  79.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-07  90  73  81.5    0.07    0.0 0
2020-07-08  87  73  80.0     T  0.0 0
2020-07-09  90  71  80.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-10  92  73  82.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-11  92  67  79.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-12  82  68  75.0    1.38    0.0 0
2020-07-13  89  69  79.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-14  91  70  80.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-15  93  70  81.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-16  91  70  80.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-17  94  73  83.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-18  95  73  84.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-19  95  73  84.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-20  95  73  84.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-21  94  74  84.0     T  0.0 0
2020-07-22  92  73  82.5    0.19    0.0 0
2020-07-23  92  71  81.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-24  90  73  81.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-25  94  72  83.0    0.07    0.0 0
2020-07-26  94  71  82.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-07-27  91  73  82.0     T  0.0 0
2020-07-28  90  72  81.0     T  0.0 0
2020-07-29  92  73  82.5    0.02    0.0 0
2020-07-30  90  74  82.0    0.14    0.0 0
2020-07-31  92  74  83.0    0.25    0.0 0
2020-08-01  87  70  78.5     T  0.0 0
2020-08-02  86  66  76.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-03  91  67  79.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-04  90  70  80.0    0.01    0.0 0
2020-08-05  92  68  80.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-06  92  71  81.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-07  94  69  81.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-08  97  68  82.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-09  96  71  83.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-10  98  74  86.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-11  95  73  84.0    0.49    0.0 0
2020-08-12  93  74  83.5    0.01    0.0 0
2020-08-13  94  71  82.5     T  0.0 0
2020-08-14  90  74  82.0     T  0.0 0
2020-08-15  92  71  81.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-16  93  67  80.0     T  0.0 0
2020-08-17  91  67  79.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-18  93  64  78.5    0.24    0.0 0
2020-08-19  91  68  79.5    1.24    0.0 0
2020-08-20  87  67  77.0     T  0.0 0
2020-08-21  82  68  75.0    0.10    0.0 0
2020-08-22  85  64  74.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-23  88  68  78.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-08-24  88  72  80.0     T  0.0 0
2020-08-25  82  72  77.0    0.15    0.0 0
2020-08-26  85  70  77.5    1.83    0.0 0
2020-08-27  91  75  83.0    0.22    0.0 0
2020-08-28  86  72  79.0    0.92    0.0 0
2020-08-29  90  74  82.0    0.02    0.0 0
2020-08-30  91  71  81.0    0.23    0.0 0
2020-08-31  87  71  79.0    0.94    0.0 0
2020-09-01  89  71  80.0    0.05    0.0 0
2020-09-02  89  74  81.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-03  89  73  81.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-04  90  67  78.5     T  0.0 0
2020-09-05  88  59  73.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-06  86  57  71.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-07  86  60  73.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-08  87  64  75.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-09  88  65  76.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-10  90  66  78.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-11  93  68  80.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-12  90  73  81.5    0.01    0.0 0
2020-09-13  91  71  81.0     T  0.0 0
2020-09-14  90  69  79.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-15  83  69  76.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-16  74  68  71.0    0.12    0.0 0
2020-09-17  87  70  78.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-18  79  61  70.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-19  76  59  67.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-20  81  58  69.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-21  76  53  64.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-22  75  51  63.0     T  0.0 0
2020-09-23  71  53  62.0    0.79    0.0 0
2020-09-24  66  55  60.5    2.65    0.0 0
2020-09-25  73  64  68.5     T  0.0 0
2020-09-26  76  62  69.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-27  83  61  72.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-28  82  56  69.0    0.42    0.0 0
2020-09-29  70  49  59.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-09-30  77  47  62.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-01  76  51  63.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-02  69  44  56.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-03  71  40  55.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-04  76  50  63.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-05  76  48  62.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-06  80  48  64.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-07  82  52  67.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-08  82  49  65.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-09  73  63  68.0    0.47    0.0 0
2020-10-10  74  64  69.0    1.35    0.0 0
2020-10-11  75  68  71.5    0.23    0.0 0
2020-10-12  80  64  72.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-13  76  52  64.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-14  82  45  63.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-15  80  54  67.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-16  66  39  52.5    0.01    0.0 0
2020-10-17  68  37  52.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-18  76  50  63.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-19  80  56  68.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-20  81  59  70.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-21  81  58  69.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-22  83  62  72.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-23  83  63  73.0    0.03    0.0 0
2020-10-24  66  55  60.5    0.44    0.0 0
2020-10-25  69  55  62.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-26  75  58  66.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-27  75  58  66.5     T  0.0 0
2020-10-28  74  69  71.5    2.87    0.0 0
2020-10-29  72  48  60.0    0.58    0.0 0
2020-10-30  57  42  49.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-10-31  68  40  54.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-01  68  43  55.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-02  57  33  45.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-03  66  34  50.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-04  71  39  55.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-05  70  44  57.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-06  76  46  61.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-07  75  48  61.5     T  0.0 0
2020-11-08  79  59  69.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-09  78  62  70.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-10  74  65  69.5     T  0.0 0
2020-11-11  77  58  67.5    0.04    0.0 0
2020-11-12  68  44  56.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-13  71  42  56.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-14  73  41  57.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-15  69  40  54.5    0.02    0.0 0
2020-11-16  63  32  47.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-17  62  34  48.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-18  64  31  47.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-19  66  38  52.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-20  72  40  56.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-21  73  42  57.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-22  69  46  57.5    0.02    0.0 0
2020-11-23  57  35  46.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-24  65  32  48.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-25  65  53  59.0    0.48    0.0 0
2020-11-26  62  40  51.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-11-27  66  38  52.0    0.58    0.0 0
2020-11-28  57  41  49.0     T  0.0 0
2020-11-29  55  39  47.0    0.73    0.0 0
2020-11-30  44  30  37.0    0.08     T  0
2020-12-01  41  25  33.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-02  52  20  36.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-03  58  25  41.5    0.16    0.0 0
2020-12-04  48  35  41.5    0.82    0.0 0
2020-12-05  56  28  42.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-06  59  30  44.5     T  0.0 0
2020-12-07  47  28  37.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-08  49  25  37.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-09  64  28  46.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-10  71  35  53.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-11  66  37  51.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-12  63  46  54.5    0.30    0.0 0
2020-12-13  60  34  47.0    0.80    0.0 0
2020-12-14  44  35  39.5    0.81    0.0 0
2020-12-15  48  30  39.0     T  0.0 0
2020-12-16  50  35  42.5    0.26    0.0 0
2020-12-17  43  26  34.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-18  50  23  36.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-19  53  27  40.0    0.03    0.0 0
2020-12-20  51  40  45.5    0.16    0.0 0
2020-12-21  61  38  49.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-22  60  31  45.5    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-23  61  35  48.0    0.12    0.0 0
2020-12-24  52  28  40.0    1.13     T  0
2020-12-25  32  20  26.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-26  50  18  34.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-27  60  26  43.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-28  57  37  47.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-29  61  33  47.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-30  69  41  55.0    0.00    0.0 0
2020-12-31  59  50  54.5    0.03    0.0 0
```

Comment: upload .csv file so that i can access it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, notice that some columns contain the value "T". To solve some of the questions, you'll have to replace those:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\users\....\DATA.csv", sep=";")
df.replace('T',0, inplace = True)
```

To get the datatypes:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 366 entries, 0 to 365
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   Date            366 non-null    object 
 1   MaxTemperature  366 non-null    int64  
 2   MinTemperature  366 non-null    int64  
 3   AvgTemperature  366 non-null    float64
 4   Precipitation   366 non-null    object 
 5   Snowfall        366 non-null    object 
 6   SnowDepth       366 non-null    int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(3), object(3)
memory usage: 20.1+ KB
```

To get all the information you ask, you need to transform `object` values to `float`. They are string because you hade "T" values instead of numeric:

```
df['Precipitation'] = df.Precipitation.astype(float)
df['Snowfall'] = df.Snowfall.astype(float)
df['SnowDepth'] = df.SnowDepth.astype(float)
```

Note now that

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 366 entries, 0 to 365
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   Date            366 non-null    object 
 1   MaxTemperature  366 non-null    int64  
 2   MinTemperature  366 non-null    int64  
 3   AvgTemperature  366 non-null    float64
 4   Precipitation   366 non-null    float64
 5   Snowfall        366 non-null    float64
 6   SnowDepth       366 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(4), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 20.1+ KB
```

Now to answer all the questions:

```
df.describe()
```

returns:

```
       MaxTemperature  MinTemperature  AvgTemperature  Precipitation  \
count      366.000000      366.000000      366.000000     366.000000   
mean        73.021858       52.229508       62.625683       0.192678   
std         14.496086       14.966696       14.317651       0.471406   
min         28.000000       18.000000       25.000000       0.000000   
25%         61.250000       40.000000       51.000000       0.000000   
50%         74.000000       53.000000       63.250000       0.000000   
75%         86.000000       67.000000       75.500000       0.140000   
max         98.000000       75.000000       86.000000       3.420000   

       Snowfall  SnowDepth  
count     366.0      366.0  
mean        0.0        0.0  
std         0.0        0.0  
min         0.0        0.0  
25%         0.0        0.0  
50%         0.0        0.0  
75%         0.0        0.0  
max         0.0        0.0
```

you have the max, min, .... for all variables.

As for the plot

```
lines = df.plot.line()
```

[image]